# Unable to run the NUnit tests on Aure release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a .netcore 3.1 Nunit project, I have build a Azure release pipeline to run the test cases on an hosted agtent and the dotnet test task fails with null pointer exception.

I am able to run the test cases on my local machine.

[image: 1]

I tried to add the .netcore 3.1 sdk package to hosted agent.

[image: 2]

Comment: Hi niko, any update?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the pipeline via selfhosted agent?

According to this post, [Upgrade of .NET agent for Azure Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/upgrade-of-net-agent-for-azure-pipelines/), .netcore 3.1 is gradually deprecated from microsoft-hosted agent.

I suppose that you could upgrade your project to dotnet 6.0 or test with [selfhosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops).